# Anyway to Hot-deploy Jar in Coldfusion 9?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jrun, hotdeploy

I was wondering if theres anyway to deploy new jar files to use in Coldfusion9 without having to restart the service.

Thanks

Bruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give [JavaLoader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) a try.

Comment: FYI: will be a standard feature in zeus

Comment: @Bruno - Just be sure to store the javaLoader in the `server` scope http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=displayPost&ID=212